# Is there a VBA formula to print an excel sheet with a drop down list at once?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, printing, drop-down-menu

[image]

I would like to be able to print all possible sheets on a single excel sheet that contains a drop down menu list.

I've tried the following VBA code:

```
Sub Iterate_Through_data_Validation()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range


'Which cell has data validation
   Set dvCell = Worksheets("Seating Chart").Range("K3")
'Determine where validation comes from
   Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value
    'add some print page code here
Next c

End Sub
```

But I am not sure what to change to make it run. I know when I run it, the `Set inputRange - Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)` gets highlighted as an error.

```
Sub Iterate_Through_data_Validation()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range


'Which cell has data validation
   Set dvCell = Worksheets("Seating Chart").Range("K3")
'Determine where validation comes from
   Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value
    'add some print page code here
Next c

End Sub
```

I would expect to be able to click print and all the possible sheets would appear on the print preview, however, I am unable to get past the VBA code portion.

Comment: My apologies, I am an amatuer when it comes to VBA

Comment: On one excel sheet, I have student information i.e. id, last name, first name, middle, and grade level. These students have been separated into different room numbers on the last column of the first sheet. I then used an array formula to transfer that information over into the next sheet on my workbook. This provides me with a seating chart of the students assigned to each of the rooms. I use the drop down to see each of the seating charts for each room.

Comment: So the 100 is the dropdown? Where is the list for that located?

Comment: Yes, the location of those numbers is on the first sheet with the student data in column J. But I used a data validation list for the drop down.

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print dvCell.Validation.Formula1`? What is the result? I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: When I debug it, it highlights that particular row

Comment: Add the line `Debug.Print dvCell.Validation.Formula1` right before, and check the result in the Immediate Window.

Comment: run-time error '424' object required

Comment: So you added the line `Debug.Print dvCell.Validation.Formula1`, and that specific line throws the error?

Comment: However, you can see the cells in the validation list like this: `Set inputRange = Range(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 actually `Evaluate` works for me. And if the `.Formula1` is `=Sheet2!$B$9:$B$13`, then your suggestion will not work.

Comment: @BigBen that's what I get for not testing properly